# Invalid parameter in PDO upon token declaration

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query that executes properly:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE ((user1 = $userid AND user1read = 'no') OR (user2 = $userid AND user2read = 'no') AND id2 = '1')");
$query->execute();
```

When I try to declare tokens, it throws an `Invalid parameter number'` fatal error. This is the code that throws the error:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE ((user1 = :userid AND user1read = 'no') OR (user2 = :userid AND user2read = 'no') AND id2 = '1')");
$query->execute(array(
'userid' => $userid
));
```

I'm trying to migrate from sql to PDO. Is there some sql remnant here that I'm missing?

Comment: RTFM says: `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement`

Source: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php

Try:

```
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE ((user1 = :userid AND user1read = 'no')     OR (user2 = :userid2 AND user2read = 'no') AND id2 = '1')");
$query->execute(array(
  'userid' => $userid,
  'userid2' => $userid
));
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to @djdy. But ,if I'm not mistaken, you can try using `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` and its will work :

```
$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, TRUE);
$query = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pm WHERE ((user1 = :userid AND user1read = 'no')     OR (user2 = :userid AND user2read = 'no') AND id2 = '1')");
$query->execute(array(
'userid' => $userid,
));
```